# No main class found when running program

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

I cannot get this program to run :

> Exercise 7.13 JHTP (Date Class): Create a class called Date that
> includes 3 instance variables—a month (type int), a day (type int),
> and a year (type int). Provide a constructor that initializes the 3
> instance variables and assumes the values provided are correct.
> Provide a set and a get method for each instance variable. Provide a
> method displayDate that displays the month, day, and year separated by
> forward slashes(/).

My code :

```
public class Date {

    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;
    
    public Date(int month, int day, int year){//constructor
        this.month = month;//initilize 
        this.day = day;
        this.year = year;
    }
    
    public void setMonth(int month){
        this.month = month;//stores the names
    }
    public void setDay(int day){
        this.day = day;
    }
    public void setYear(int year){
        this.year = year;
    }
    public int getMonth(){
        return month;//return value

    }
    public int getDay(){
      return day;
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }
    public String displayDate(){

        return month + "/" + day + "/" + "/" + year;
   

    }
}
```

I tried adding `public static void main(String[] args)` but, then I just got a bunch of errors

Comment: Hello, and welcome here ! I am not sure Stackoverflow is the good place for us to resolve your excercice. Anyway, you have to give details about your errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a main method inside your class.

```
public class Date {

    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    public Date(int month, int day, int year){//constructor
        this.month = month;//initilize
        this.day = day;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month){
        this.month = month;//stores the names
    }
    public void setDay(int day){
        this.day = day;
    }
    public void setYear(int year){
        this.year = year;
    }
    public int getMonth(){
        return month;//return value

    }
    public int getDay(){
        return day;
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }
    public String displayDate(){

        return month + "/" + day + "/" + "/" + year;


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date(11,11,1991);
        System.out.println(date.displayDate());
    }
}
```

If you're using InteliJ, to run the code, right click inside the main method and "Run Date.main()"

This is good for testing purposes, but in an actual program, you would be calling the Date class inside other classes in your package.